# Which code pattern to use for Bot builder sdk 4 nodejs?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am looking at the code sample, [14.nlp-with-dispatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch) which makes use of Dispatch, LUIS, and QnA Maker. Before looking at this code I had downloaded a NodeJS sample from the page [Use multiple LUIS and QnA models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&branch=master&tabs=csharp), which looked like:

```
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, BotStateSet, ConversationState, MemoryStorage, TurnContext, UserState } = require('botbuilder');
const { LuisRecognizer, QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');
const { DialogSet } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const restify = require('restify');

// Create server
let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log(`${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});

// Create adapter
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: '',
    appPassword: ''
});

const dispatcher = new LuisRecognizer({
    appId: '',
    subscriptionKey: '',
    serviceEndpoint: '',
    verbose: true
});

//LUIS homeautomatio app
const homeAutomation = new LuisRecognizer({
    appId: '',
    subscriptionKey: '',
    serviceEndpoint: '',
    verbose: true
});

// LUIS `weather app`
const weather = new LuisRecognizer({
    appId: '',
    subscriptionKey: '',
    serviceEndpoint: '',
    verbose: true
});

// The QnA
const faq = new QnAMaker(
    {
        knowledgeBaseId: '',
        endpointKey: '',
        host: ''
    },
    {
        answerBeforeNext: true
    }
);

// Add state middleware
const storage = new MemoryStorage();
const convoState = new ConversationState(storage);
const userState = new UserState(storage);
adapter.use(new BotStateSet(convoState, userState));

// Register some dialogs for usage with the LUIS apps that are being dispatched to
const dialogs = new DialogSet();

// Helper function to retrieve specific entities from LUIS results
function findEntities(entityName, entityResults) {
    let entities = []
    if (entityName in entityResults) {
        entityResults[entityName].forEach(entity => {
            entities.push(entity);
        });
    }
    return entities.length > 0 ? entities : undefined;
}

// Setup dialogs
dialogs.add('HomeAutomation_TurnOn', [
    async (dialogContext, args) => {
        const devices = findEntities('HomeAutomation_Device', args.entities);
        const operations = findEntities('HomeAutomation_Operation', args.entities);

        const state = convoState.get(dialogContext.context);
        state.homeAutomationTurnOn = state.homeAutomationTurnOn ? state.homeAutomationTurnOn + 1 : 1;
        await dialogContext.context.sendActivity(`${state.homeAutomationTurnOn}: You reached the "HomeAutomation_TurnOn" dialog.`);
        if (devices) {
            await dialogContext.context.sendActivity(`Found these "HomeAutomation_Device" entities:\n${devices.join(', ')}`);
        }
        if (operations) {
            await dialogContext.context.sendActivity(`Found these "HomeAutomation_Operation" entities:\n${operations.join(', ')}`);
        }
        await dialogContext.end();
    }
]);

dialogs.add('Weather_GetCondition', [
    async (dialogContext, args) => {
        const locations = findEntities('Weather_Location', args.entities);

        const state = convoState.get(dialogContext.context);
        state.weatherGetCondition = state.weatherGetCondition ? state.weatherGetCondition + 1 : 1;
        await dialogContext.context.sendActivity(`${state.weatherGetCondition}: You reached the "Weather_GetCondition" dialog.`);
        if (locations) {
            await dialogContext.context.sendActivity(`Found these "Weather_Location" entities:\n${locations.join(', ')}`);
        }
        await dialogContext.end();
    }
]);

adapter.use(dispatcher);

// Listen for incoming Activities
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        if (context.activity.type === 'message') {
            //the dialog set requires use of a state property accessor to access the dialog state
            const state = convoState.get(context);
            const dc = dialogs.createContext(context, state);

            // Retrieve the LUIS results from our dispatcher LUIS application
            const luisResults = dispatcher.get(context);

            // Extract the top intent from LUIS and use it to select which LUIS application to dispatch to
            const topIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResults);

            const isMessage = context.activity.type === 'message';
            if (isMessage) {
                switch (topIntent) {
                    case 'l_homeautomation':
                        //Call luis.
                        const homeAutoResults = await homeAutomation.recognize(context);
                        const topHomeAutoIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(homeAutoResults);
                        // topHomeAutoIntent = HomeAutomation_TurnOn
                        await dc.begin(topHomeAutoIntent, homeAutoResults);
                        break;
                    case 'l_weather':
                        const weatherResults = await weather.recognize(context);
                        const topWeatherIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(weatherResults);
                        await dc.begin(topWeatherIntent, weatherResults);
                        break;
                    case 'q_FAQ':
                        await faq.answer(context);
                        break;
                    default:
                        await dc.begin('None');
                }
            }

            if (!context.responded) {
                await dc.continue();
                if (!context.responded && isMessage) {
                    await dc.context.sendActivity(`Hi! I'm the LUIS dispatch bot. Say something and LUIS will decide how the message should be routed.`);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The above code looks very different from what's in the 14.nlp-with-dispatch sample when it comes to designing, defining and triggering dialogs.

Have new coding patterns been introduced. If so, which should be follow and which are still supported?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the example set out by the github repo [14. NLP-with-Dispatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch). The code in the tutorial you linked is rather simplified, so it can be compressed to a single file. It is only meant to show the how the routing for multiple LUIS and/or QnA models *can* be used. The Github sample is more robust, showing further customization.